# Ajax call work perfectly in Firefox, Chrome & IE9+ and but does not work in IE8 or IE7-Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, prototypejs

I have the ajax call with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome & IE9+ and  but does not work in IE8 or IE7.

I am using [Prototypejs](http://api.prototypejs.org/) I have tried with [Ajax.Request](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/) but getting same issue.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following? Do I have to use [XDomainRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx) for this.

**Code:**

```
            var grt = $F('Type1');
            var serviceUrl = serviceURI.restfulURL;
            serviceUrl = serviceUrl
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", serviceUrl, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
                           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                           var responseData=xmlhttp.responseText;
                           if (responseData == null
                                    || responseData == "") {
                                var ele = document
                                        .getElementById('table1');
                                ele.innerHTML = "";
                                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                                ele.appendChild(tr);
                                var td = document.createElement('td');
                                tr.appendChild(td);
                                var txt = document
                                        .createTextNode(data1);
                                td.appendChild(txt);
                            } else {
                                var ele = document
                                        .getElementById('table1');
                                ele.innerHTML = "";
                                var jsonString = JSON
                                        .parse(responseData);


                                    var tr = document
                                            .createElement('tr');
                                    else.appendChild(tr);
                                    var td = document
                                            .createElement('td');
                                    tr.appendChild(td);
                                    var txt = document
                                            .createTextNode(data2);
                                    td.appendChild(txt);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

            return false;
```

Comment: "Do I have to use XDomainRequest object for this" — Is it a cross-origin request?

Comment: "does not work in IE8 or IE7" — Do you *really* need to support those ancient, buggy excuses for browsers which [Microsoft does not even supply security fixes for](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support?wa=wsignin1.0)? (Maybe you do, but maybe it is something you can push back on).

Comment: No it is not CORS. I know it is old and not reliable, but unfortunately I need this.